# Me ajude a funcionar esse código

Tags: javascript

Como faço pra manter o código funcionando da mesma maneira tirando o "break" após o "if"?: var numeroTentativa = 1;

```
     while (numeroTentativa > 0) {

        var chute = parseInt(prompt('Digite o número pensado:'));
        var numeroPensado = Math.round(Math.random()*10);

        if (chute === numeroPensado) {
            alert('Parábens, eu pensei exatamento no número ' + numeroPensado + '.');
            break;
        } else if (numeroPensado < chute){
            alert('Você digitou um número maior em relação ao que eu pensei, continue tentando.');
        } else if (numeroPensado > chute) {
            alert ('Você digitou um número menor em relação ao que eu pensei, continue tentando.');
        } 

        numeroTentativa++;

        alert('Eu pensei no número: ' + numeroPensado);

    }
```

Comment: Depende! O que o código deveria fazer? E o que ele está fazendo agora? Qual é o real problema de se possuir o `break` que justifica você querer removê-lo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma bem simples:

Cria uma variável booleana com o valor como verdadeiro, ela será usada para validar se deve ser continuando a executar o loop, em vez de usar o `break` você apenas muda a variável para falso, assim o loop será interrompido na **próxima** iteração. Para interromper o restante do código seguinte a cadeia `if else`, basta agrupar tudo dentro do um `else`

```
var bool = true;

while (numeroTentativa > 0 || bool) {
  var chute = parseInt(prompt('Digite o número pensado:'));
  var numeroPensado = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);

  if (chute === numeroPensado) {
    alert('Parábens, eu pensei exatamento no número ' + numeroPensado + '.');
    bool = false;
  } else {
    if (numeroPensado < chute) {
      alert('Você digitou um número maior em relação ao que eu pensei, continue tentando.');
    } else if (numeroPensado > chute) {
      alert('Você digitou um número menor em relação ao que eu pensei, continue tentando.');
    }

    numeroTentativa++;

    alert('Eu pensei no número: ' + numeroPensado);
  }
}
```

Essa é uma solução, porém é uma solução para um problema que não existe, afinal não tem nada de errado usar o comando `break`

Comment: Valeu, funcionou!!

Answer (score 0):

Como são 3 condições possíveis:

1. Número igual,
2. número maior, e
3. número menor

Você poderia usar apenas um `if` (igual), `else if` (maior) e `else` (menor). Isso porque se nenhuma das duas primeiras condições forem atendidas, só poderá ser a terceira (`else`).

E você tem que fazer um `break` após o `alert` usando a mesma condição proposta na resposta do Costamilam (a variável `bool`), para interromper o laço `while` caso tenha acertado o número, senão irá virar um looping infinito:

```js
var bool;
var numeroTentativa = 0;

while(numeroTentativa > 0 || !bool){
   var chute = parseInt(prompt('Digite o número pensado:'));
   var numeroPensado = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);

   if(chute === numeroPensado){
      alert('Parábens, eu pensei exatamento no número ' + numeroPensado + '.');
      bool = true;
   }else if(numeroPensado < chute){
      alert('Você digitou um número maior em relação ao que eu pensei, continue tentando.');
   }else{
      alert('Você digitou um número menor em relação ao que eu pensei, continue tentando.');
   }

   numeroTentativa++;

   alert('Eu pensei no número: ' + numeroPensado);
   if(bool) break;
}
```